# ImageAdapter extending BaseAdapter is not getting called after the Fragment is destroyed inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-viewpager, baseadapter

FragmentPhotos: THIS IS A FRAGMENT INSIDE A VIEWPAGER, WHICH IS ITSELF INSIDE A FRAGMENT OF A VIEWPAGER OF AN ACTIVITY. The situation is like this:

I HAVE A ACTIVITY WHICH HAS A VIEWPAGER, INSIDE THIS VIEWPAGER THERE ARE 5 FRAGMENTS. INSIDE THE 2ND FRAGMENT(FRAGMENT_GALLERY), I AM HAVING A ANOTHER VIEWPAGER. INSIDE THIS VIEWPAGER I AM HAVING A FRAGMENT NAMED FRAGMENT_PHOTOS, INSIDE THIS FRAGMENT(FRAGMENT_PHOTOS) THERE IS A GRIDVIEW, WHICH ONLY GETS POPULATED FOR THE FIRST TIME I OPEN THE APP USING AN IMAGEADAPTER(IMAGEADAPTER IS EXTENDING BASEADAPTER). AND ALSO STAYS POPULATED(SHOWS IMAGES) WHEN I NAVIGATE TO THE VERY NEXT FRAGMENT OR THE VERY PREVIOUS FRAGMENT. BUT WHEN I  NAVIGATE TO SOME OTHER FRAGMENTS(SAY #4 OR #5) AND GET BACK TO THIS FRAGMENT(FRAGMENT PHOTOS) THE GRIDVIEW DOES NOT GETS POPULATED OR DOES NOT SHOWS IMAGES(AS ACCORDING TO MY DIAGNOSIS THE IMAGEADAPTER DOES NOT GETS CALLED AGAIN). IT IS ONLY GETTING CALLED ONCE(WHEN WE OPEN THE APP). Please help me...

1. When app opens, the Girdview inside fragment of viewpager works properly and imageadapter populates the images in it for the first time.
2. Now when i navigate to the next fragment and get back to the same fragment(FragmentPhotos), the gridview shows the images properly..
3. But when I navigate to a different fragment(say #4 or #5) then the gridview inside FragmentPhotos does not shows images.
   According to my diagnosis the imageadapter is not giving response again

   public class FragmentPhotos extends Fragment {

   ```
   private GridView gridView;
   private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
   private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
   private DisplayMetrics display;
   private ArrayList<String> imagesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
   private ArrayList<String> foldersArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
   private View rootView;
   private final int REQUEST_CODE=1;
   private ImageView imgEnlarged;
   private GetImagesFromCard imagesFromCardTask;
   private Context context;

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);
       initUI(rootView);
       return rootView;
   }

   public void initGallery()
   {
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
           requestPermissions(AppClass.INITIAL_PERMS, REQUEST_CODE);
       }
       else
       {
           if (imagesFromCardTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING))
           {

           }
           else
           {
               imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(context);
               gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
               new GetImagesFromCard().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart() {
       context = this.getActivity();
       imagesFromCardTask = new GetImagesFromCard();
       super.onStart();
   }

   public void disableGalleryTask()
   {
       if (imagesFromCardTask.getStatus()==GetImagesFromCard.Status.RUNNING)
       {
           imagesFromCardTask.cancel(true);
       }
   }

   private void initUI(View view) {
       display = new DisplayMetrics();
       getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(display);
       gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
       imgEnlarged = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgEnlarged);
       gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               showImageEnlarged(position);
           }
       });
       Log.e("","Gallery initialized");
   }

   private class GetImagesFromCard extends AsyncTask<Void,LoadedImage,Void>
   {
       Bitmap bitmap;
       ArrayList<LoadedImage> bitmapArrays=new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
           String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN};
           String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
           Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy);
           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
           int size = cursor.getCount();
           if (size==0)
           {

           }
           int imageId =0;
           int i=0;
           while (i<size && !isCancelled())
           {
               cursor.moveToPosition(i);
               imageId = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
               uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageId);
               publishProgress(new LoadedImage(uri.toString()));
               if (i==0)
               {
                   showImageEnlarged(uri);
               }
               i++;
           }
           cursor.close();
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... values) {
           super.onProgressUpdate(values);
           for (LoadedImage photo: values)
           {
               imageAdapter.addPhoto(photo);
               imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               bitmapArrays.add(photo);
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCancelled() {
           Log.e("","Task Cancelled");
           super.onCancelled();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       switch (requestCode)
       {
           case REQUEST_CODE:
           {
               for (int i=0;i<grantResults.length;i++)
               {
                   if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                   {
                       Log.e("Permission Granted", permissions[i]);
                   }
               }
               new GetImagesFromCard().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Following is my ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
    ArrayList<LoadedImage> bitmapString;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        Log.e("","ImageAdapter called");
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();

        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        bitmapString = new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();

        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
                .build();

    }

    public void addPhoto(LoadedImage photo)
    {
        bitmapString.add(photo);
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        bitmapString.clear();
    }

    public void remove(int index)
    {
        bitmapString.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bitmapString.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos_grid_items,parent,false);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgGallery);
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
        imageLoader.displayImage(bitmapString.get(position).getImgString(),holder.imageView,options);
        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Following is my ViewPager Adapter:

```
public class GalleryViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    int numOfTabs;

    public GalleryViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your Viewpager Adapter

Comment: From where are you calling your initGallery method?

Comment: Thanks Akshay, but the the gridview does not shows images even if i call the ImageAdapter by imageadapter(getActivity). ??

Comment: I am calling the initGallery() from outside the this viewpager(called GalleryViewPager). I am calling it from the activity.

Comment: The ImageAdapter does not populates the gridview once the fragment carrying this gridview is destroyed.. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getActivity()` inside `onCreateView()`, because the activity might not be created yet. Get the context in `onActivityCreated()`. And also since your `InitUI(view)` method uses context, you have to call that method in `onActivityCreated()` instead.

**EDIT 1:**
Call `initGallery()` in `onStart()` or `onResume()` in fragment.
and call `disableGalleryTask()` in `onPause()` or `onStop()` in fragment.

So that when the view is visible to user, then only the `initGallery()` is called.

Comment: I am calling the initGallery() from outside the this viewpager(called GalleryViewPager). I am calling it from the activity.

Comment: Are you calling `initGallery()` when the fragment is recreated?

Comment: Actually I am calling initGallery() in onPageSelected of this ViewPager

Comment: Because i want to start the gridview populating asynctask when we enter this fragment.. Please help me.. Do i need to provide more info..

Answer (score 0):

Call your initGallery() method in below overriden method in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
       initGallery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved !!!

Actually when i added this fragment(FragmentPhotos - which is carrying the gridview), was added in the viewpager in a wrong manner -

`ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());` //Remove this

//Add this

`ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

Thankyou so much everyone for your help..